# Careers account refuses to link to stackoverflow account

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, merge-accounts

I have >400 reputation on stack overflow, but my careers profile refuses to acknowledge that I have any stack overflow, programming, or server fault accounts.  All of the stack overflow question sites are linked together under one account, but my careers account will not acknowledge this.  In the stack exchange section of my careers profile there is an empty list of sites to associate with.  However yesterday this was not the case, it listed my programming and server fault accounts, but not my stack overflow account where I have actually answered things.

I know that initially I created the stack overflow account linking to a livejournal openid, and the careers was initially linked to a google openid, but both sets of accounts have both openids.

I notice based on all of the similar questions to this that a common solution is to merge the accounts somehow?

It seems like this is a common problem, perhaps instead of going through support like this it would be useful if there was a way for a user to suggest their accounts should be merged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had accounts merged on the network earlier today.  The account ids on careers update at regular intervals and your time just hadn't come up yet.  I'll manually change it this time, but in all likelihood it would have fixed itself before you wake up tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you, I would have waited longer had it not deleted the cross-link to the other two accounts, suggesting it was regressing.  I appreciate your help though.

Comment: Also, thanks for mentioning the regular intervals, I wasn't trying to ask a duplicate question, but every other answer to an account merge question seemed to require someone to manually fix the problem.

Comment: @Nick Larsen: I have the same problem as dgtized.
Careers profile: https://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/info/435657, and Stack Overflow profile: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3948809/nikola-tulimirovic.